# Корректное позиционирование элементов (тегов) в блоке boostrap

Tags: css, позиционирование, теги

Есть блог на джанго, на который были внедрены теги (django-taggit). Теги отображаются на трех страницах: **url.com/blog**, **url.com/tag/"tag_name"** и **url.com/"post_name"**

Скрины:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8DHNw.jpg

Я хочу что-бы эти теги отображались как на верхнем скрине.

А вот какие проблемы возникают при разных сценариях:

**FIXED** 1) На странице поиска постов по тегам **url.com/tag/"tag_name"** если в после "слишком много" тегов - они сливаются (см. средний скрин) --- хочется что-бы между ними появилось необходимое пространство.

2) На странице списка постов **url.com/blog** если в посте снова "много тегов", они съезжают вниз под кнопку "View" и прячутся за следующим постом (см. нижний скрин) --- хочется что-бы вне зависимости от количества тегов они а) всегда были на одном уровне с кнопкой "View" и просто уходили вниз, б) не выходили за рамки (что-бы рамка расширялась при необходимости)

3) При уменьшении экрана (мобильная версия) рамка вместе с контентом прекрасно адаптируется и уменьшается, но теги в нем, соответственно нет. Они съезжают под кнопку "View", выходят за рамку и залезают под следующий пост. Это тоже хочется исправить (не хочется отказываться от тегов на мобильных устройствах).

Часть кода **url.com/blog**:

HTML:

```
<div class='col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2'>
{% for obj in object_list %}
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">

    <div class="thumbnail">
....
        {% if obj.tags.names %}
    <ul class="post-tags">
        {% for tag in obj.tags.names %}
            <li>
            <a class="tag-click" href="/tag/{{ obj.tags.slugs|get_at_index:forloop.counter0 }}">{{ tag }}</a>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
    <br/>
    <br/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<hr/>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

CSS:

```
.post-tags {
margin:0;
padding: 0;
float: right;
list-style: none outside;
height: 18px;
}

.post-tags li {
float:left;
background-color:#0070ad;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
padding: 5px 10px;
font-size: 12px;
font-family: Merriweather;
border-radius: 5px;
}

.post-tags li a {
color:#fff;
display: block;
height: 100%;
}
```

**FIXED**

Код **url.com/tag/"tag_name"**:

HTML

```
<div class='col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2' id="detail_view">


{% if posts_with_tag %}
        {% for post in posts_with_tag %}
            <div class="post-preview">
                <a class="heading" href="{% url 'posts:list' %}{{ post.slug }}/">{{ post.title }}</a><br>
                <p class="text">{{ post.preview_content|safe|truncatechars:300 }}</p>
                <p class="publish_date"> Posted: {{ post.publish }}</p>
                {% for post_tag in post.tags.names %}

                    <span class="tags">{{ post_tag }}</span>

                {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <br>
            <hr>
        {% endfor %}
{% endif %}

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#tags-detail {
float: left;
}

.post-tags li:hover {
background-color: #025f91;
}

.post-tags li a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

.tags {
background-color:#0070ad;
padding: 5px 6px;
margin-right: 5px;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1.3333333;
font-family: Merriweather;
border-radius: 5px;
color: white;
}
```

Многие дни правок разнообразных padding, margin, position и т.д. и т.п. ни к чему толковому не привели. Постоянно что-то вылазит за рамки, пропадает, смещается и слезает.

Хочется что-бы вне зависимости от количества тегов и ширины экрана, теги были адаптивными (насколько это возможно) и всегда отображались адекватно. Буду крайне признателен за любой совет, который поможет сойти с мертвой точки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. У `.tags` увеличьте значение `line-height` до 2 и более единиц.
2. У `.post-tags` уберите `height: 18px;`.
3. Тут скорее всего нужно `clear: both` прописать или же через media сделать теги меньше. Не могу сказать точно, через отладчик все работает корректно. Возможно просто нужно применить пункты 1 и 2.

Comment: Спасибо!  1. Помогло, поставив 2.3 проблема решилась. 2. Убрал - кнопки "ушли в пол", поставил вместо height 18px - 2.5%, но проблема не решилась. 3. Так же считаю, что сперва стоит решить первые вопросы (первый решен, второй - нет) и, возможно, проблема уйдет. Если нет - дальше буду решать.

Comment: @BlyzniukEvhen уберите height совсем

Comment: если полностью height из .post-tags получается это https://imgur.com/HqqrqZN

Comment: @BlyzniukEvhen Это `li` увеличивается. Посмотрите в отладке, скорее всего дополнительно применяются какие-то другие стили. Высота должна регулироваться содержимым, а у Вас занимает всю доступное пространство. Попробуйте `display: 100%` поставить.

Comment: @BlyzniukEvhen https://jsfiddle.net/6zma0mov/

Comment: Найти зависимость с li пока что не удалось. Полагаю Вы имели ввиду height: 100% - к сожалению это не помогло, хотя применял к .post-tags и .post-tags li. Но есть небольшой прогресс: поставив height: 3% к .post-tags li теги перестали съезжать ПОД следующий пост, хотя также спускаются ниже кнопки и выходить на нижнюю границу.

Comment: @BlyzniukEvhen Если зальете эту часть верстки на  jsfiddle.net или codepen.io , то я скорее всего найду ошибку. Трудно в уме это визуализировать.

Comment: https://codepen.io/krvstk/pen/XegEYx - примерно так

Comment: `br { clear: both; }` поставьте в конец, а в `.post-tags li` уберите `height: 3.5%;`

Comment: У `post-tags` уберите `float: right;`. Тегу `p` в который завернута кнопка присвойте класс, например, `.button_view` и задайте ему `float: left;`, еще можно `margin: 0 20px 0 0;` для красоты.

Comment: Докладываю: Ваши ответы очень помогли и в данный момент виден большой прогресс. 1) Теги на одном уровне с кнопкой, 2) Теги не выходят за нижнюю границу рамки, соответственно не залезают под следующий пост. Задача решена на 90%. Осталось 2 пожелания: хочется сделать что-бы кнопка отталкивалась от левого края вправо, а теги от правого края отталкивались влево (по типу как в Word или Writer etc текст "по правому краю" и "по левому краю"). А вот height удалить не могу, т.к. теги "уходят в пол". Думаю задать 25px и сделать несколько @media на меньше экраны.

Comment: @BlyzniukEvhen так? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boRZEE